# ¿Cómo filtrar con PHPExcel (setFilterType)?

Tags: php7, phpexcel, phpspreadsheet

Estoy realizando una página web que arroja un resumen de todos los registros de los proyectos en distintas sedes de una institución educativa.
 Al darle click en la opción de descargar, me lee y modifica una plantilla Excel con PhpSpreadSheet.

Tengo este código:

```
$doc=$_SESSION['documento'];

$consultar_usuario=mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE documento_usuario='$doc'");

while ($u=mysqli_fetch_array($consultar_usuario)) {

if (isset($u['id_ciudad']) || $u['id_ciudad']!=NULL) {

    $ic=$i['id_ciudad'];

    $consultar_ciudad=mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT * FROM ciudades WHERE id_ciudad='$ic'");

    while ($icc=mysqli_fetch_array($consultar_ciudad)) {

        $filtro=$icc['nombre_ciudad'];

    }

}elseif (isset($u['id_centro']) || $u['id_centro']!=NULL) {

    $ic=$u['id_centro'];

    $consultar_centro=mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT * FROM ciudades WHERE id_ciudad='$ic'");

    while ($icc=mysqli_fetch_array($consultar_centro)) {

        $filtro=$icc['nombre_centro'];

    }

}

}
```

Así busco el dato que deseo filtrar. Y así hago el intento de filtrar:

```
$columnFilter='';
$columnFilter->setFilterType(

 \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Worksheet\AutoFilter\Column::AUTOFILTER_FILTERTYPE_CUSTOMFILTER
);

$columnFilter->createRule()
 ->setRule(
 \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Worksheet\AutoFilter\Column\Rule::AUTOFILTER_COLUMN_RULE_EQUAL,
$filtro
);
 $escritor=new Xlsx($spreadsheet);
 $escritor->save('./archivos/DATOS - ' . $ordenado . '.xlsx');
 header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=DATOS - " . $ordenado . ".xlsx");
 header("Content-type: xls");
readfile("./archivos/DATOS - " . $ordenado . ".xlsx");
```

A pesar de que así lo indica la documentación oficial, me sale este error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function setFilterType() on string in C:\Xampp\htdocs\ValTec\estruct\estadisticas.php:255 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\Xampp\htdocs\ValTec\estruct\estadisticas.php on line 255
```

No sé si me toca usar la clase, o qué hacer. Y así inicio todas las clases.

```
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Writer\Xlsx;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Spreadsheet;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Reader\Xls;
//use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Worksheet\AutoFilter\Column;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Worksheet\AutoFilter;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Worksheet\AutoFilter\Column\Column;
```